# Android content does not show correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-constraintlayout, android-layout-weight

I'm developing an android app in Constraint layout that contains different fields such as ImageView,TextView,Buttons and EditText. It is diplaying well in design view of my android studio but it does not display full content on phones ? It also display them in an irregular script as I have set in my android studio.

[this is how it appears on phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVnWU.jpg)

This is my code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/siba"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="68dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="440dp"
        android:text="@string/ibiro"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button4" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumber3"
        android:layout_width="155dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="236dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="440dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/kgs"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="number|text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="107dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="72dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="380dp"
        android:text="@string/uburebure"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumber5"
        android:layout_width="162dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="232dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="332dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/m"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="number|text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shaka"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="104dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="320dp"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:text="@string/shaka"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="218dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="124dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="360dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:text="@string/bmi"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:text="@string/byinshi"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:text="Terms of use"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="124dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="584dp"
        android:text="Languages"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="113dp"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.06"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"


        android:layout_marginBottom="584dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your layout seems will not be proper in all other devices too as your margins for views are too bad. You have to do as per _ConstrainLayout_.

Comment: Do not hard code the width and height of the view, as it will display differently on different devices. If you use `ConstraintLayout`, you should bind views to other views. You can refer to the tutorial about [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/constraint-layout#0).

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Answer (score 0):

You have your constraints assigned to `parent` in most of your views

`... app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />`

so they will kinda overlap each other. You should constraint them logically to each other, not always the parent like in your case.

You should check this [training](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) before you try to work with ConstraintLayouts